# Migrating existing metadata from metastore(derby) and data from Hive 1.2 to Hive 2.4.3

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-metastore

I have freshly deployed Hive 2.4.3, however there are few existing tables with partition on older version of the Hive 1.2, I am using Derby as metadata store.

What is the best way to migrate them to new installation of Hive?

Answer (score 0):

Create external tables in new hive and use this command to create partitions metadata

```
MSCK [REPAIR] TABLE tablename;
```

The equivalent command on Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR)'s version of Hive is:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename RECOVER PARTITIONS;
```

This will add Hive partitions metadata. See manual on both commands here: [RECOVER PARTITIONS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE))

Comment: There are many tables and we can not keep on creating them, is there any possibility of using any tool to dump the derby for Hive 1.2 and load same dump to Hive 2.4?